# Firefox Border Radius Not Showing

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am using the following css

```
#helper{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
}

#key{
width:950px;
margin:0 auto;
z-index:2;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:8px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:8px;
}


<-- inside body -->
<div id="helper">
<div id="key">SHould be rounded top corners?</div>
</div>
```

Yet in Firefox it is not showing after refresh. Any ideas where should I be looking first? Thanks

Comment: Use Web Developer ( https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/ ) to edit CSS on the fly in Firefox. Try pressing Shift + Refresh button to force caching bypass.

Comment: Works for me, given a background or border on `#key` so you can see the corners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify a background or border for the #key element?

Comment: My page includes a google map so I also changed the id name incase #key was used by google maps api. Added background color, and padding:0 also. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## key{

```
width:950px;
margin:0 auto;
z-index:2;
border:1px solid #000;
background-color:#F00;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:8px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:8px;
}
```

you should use border or background for this.

Answer (score 0):

Nice Question Harry;

It maybe cause  we add two lines. Firefox 14 may likes all four corners in css.

Replace 2 lines 
-moz-border-radius-topleft:8px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:8px;

with 4 lines
border-top-left-radius:18px;
border-top-right-radius:18px;
border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
border-bottom-right-radius:0px;

for your example:

## key

{
width:290px; 
margin:0 auto;
border:4px solid #000;
ackground-color:#EE7621;
border-top-left-radius:18px;
border-top-right-radius:18px;
border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
padding:5px 0 0 15px;
}

jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ccatto/7zAXC/

We could also use the css as a class and id: http://jsfiddle.net/dFTMh/.

Thx;